# Plot a histogram with densities past initialization

Tags: r, histogram

This code will create two plots.

```
a = c(0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9)
b = hist(a, freq=FALSE)
dev.new()
plot(b)
```

The first is a histogram of the density (which I want to have). But if one would like to plot b later on, it will always be plotted as frequency.

Is there any chance to plot the histogram as density past initialisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the argument in `plot`

```
plot(b,freq=FALSE)
```

Comment: Wow! Did not try the obvious :)

Comment: The reason is actually quite subtle, the method `plot` for the object `histogram` contains as said a `freq` arguments which (quite disappointingly) override the `freq` in the `hist` call.